# Escaping quotes: `grep -w "label for=\"id_query"` does not work

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I want to match the exact string `label for="id_query` in a file in the current directory.
However, `grep -w "label for=\"id_query" .` does not match. Any idea how I can successfully escape that double quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use single quotes instead.

```
grep -w 'label for="id_query'
```